How to deal with the N-gens and Sharp Egdes for 3D game environment asset modeling?
I'm new and learning 3D game environment asset modeling. I am modeling a FN SCAR by follwing a tutorial
I have  questions:
When modeling in Blender, we will use Shade Smooth by Angle to see the effect, where we will set some edges as Shape edges. I would like to know what to do with these edges when we finish modeling and want to import the model into Unreal Engine?


Hello and welcome to BSE. To ensure clarity and focus in our answers, we ask that each post contains only one question. This helps the community provide more precise and helpful responses. Could you please [edit] your post to focus on a single question? You can ask additional questions in separate posts.

You've marked these edges as sharp, it should stay sharp in the game engine if this is your question

@moonboots, Yes! That is what I want to know. Thank you!
